# Windows Network File Transfer to Samba server: “Are you sure you want to copy this file without its properties?”

Tags: windows-7, samba, network-share, file-sharing

I am transferring a lot of files to a new NAS based on OpenMediaVault, with the Samba 3.5.6 service running. I am transferring from Windows 7 64-bit to the NAS, and on some media files Windows is prompting about losing some property data across the transfer.

[image: Windows Property Loss dialog box]

I have never seen this before when transferring to Samba boxes I have built myself (vs this turnkey solution), so I'm guessing there must be a Samba setting I can change to preserve the file properties in question instead of permanently losing whatever they contain (Date Taken? Exposure? Flash Fired? etc). Or maybe I've just never encountered this before; I'm really not sure.

I tried adding `ea support = yes` and `store dos attributes = yes` to the `[global]` section, but the problem remains. The Linux file system is `ext4` mounted with `user_xattr` (full options: `defaults,acl,user_xattr,noexec,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0`) as Samba requires. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Samba config:**

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %h server
include = /etc/samba/dhcp.conf
dns proxy = no
log level = 2
syslog = 2
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog only = yes
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
encrypt passwords = true
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = no
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY
guest account = nobody
load printers = no
disable spoolss = yes
printing = bsd
printcap name = /dev/null
unix extensions = yes
wide links = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
use sendfile = no
null passwords = no
local master = yes
time server = yes
wins support = yes
ea support = yes
store dos attributes = yes
```

Note: I found this [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/403870/are-you-sure-you-want-to-copy-this-file-without-its-properties), but it explains the loss due to the user trying to transfer from NTFS to FAT32.

Comment: Closed as off-topic? Questions about optimally configuring a file server are not permitted on ServerFault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're losing the "properties" copying these files is the same as the reason described in the related question you linked. Ext4 doesn't support the Alternate Data Stream (ADS) functionality that NTFS does.

It's on the [Samba3 Roadmap](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba3) to support alternate data streams, and I see the [vfs_streams_xattr](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/vfs_streams_xattr.8.html) configuration directive in the documentation but it looks like support is still kinda dodgy. The warning on the man page about limitations in the size of ADS that can be stored in xattrs.

Comment: I overlooked the ADS part, so I was looking in the wrong place. Thank you very much! I don't know why my "file server" question was voted off-topic for ServerFault, so also thank you for helping before it got closed.

Comment: @jimp - Glad I could help. I'll withhold speculation about why the question might have been closed.